# $\forall a>0$, prove that $\int_{0}^{a} x^{-1/2} \operatorname e^{2x}\operatorname d\!x\le \frac{3}{2}a^{1/6}\operatorname e^{2a}$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

> Let a>0
>
> Prove with Hölder's Inequality that;
>
> $$\int\limits_{x=0}^{x=a} x^{-1/2} \operatorname e^{2x}\operatorname d\!x\le \frac{3}{2}a^{1/6}\operatorname e^{2a}$$

this was a question, asked at the exam today. and I couldn't solve it.

I mean if you find some p and q and consider the second integral  $(\int_{0}^{a} (e^{2x})^q)^{1/q}$

you always get $(\frac{e^{2aq}-1}{2q})^{1/q}$. and you cannot simplify it.

Comment: You may use gamma function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:  Let $q=3$ and use the obvious inequality

$$(e^{6a}-1)^{1/3}\lt e^{2a}$$

Comment: exponents are ok, but for the coefficient i have to estimate again.

Comment: @derivative, I'm not sure what you mean.  Do you want me to elaborate on the answer?

Comment: i get $4^{2/3}a^{1/6}e^{2a}$

Comment: Don't forget the $2q$ that shows up in the denominator of your second integral!